# Devise routes for authenticated, unauthenticated and root paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to dynamically set the `root_path` based on whether or not a user is signed in. I've tried many variations, but cannot route an authenticated user to `static_pages#index` when they use the root URL `www.mysite.com/`. I am still new to rails and have seen similar questions asked but nothing worked for me (or I didn't implement the solution correctly).

My `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users

authenticated :user do
  root 'static_pages#index', as: :authenticated_root
end

unauthenticated :user do
  root 'static_pages#landing', as: :unauthenticated_root
end
```

When I run `rake routes`, I see both the `authenticated_root` and `unauthenticated_root`. When I use these in in views, I get errors like:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `authenticated_root' for #<#<Class:0x007ff8c37830e8>:0x007ff8c997e5b8>)
```

**Ideal Solution:**
To define the `root_path` by authentication. So, if the user is `authenticated` then `root_path` is `static_pages#index`, if they aren't then it's `static_pages#landing`. I'm not sure if this is possible in `rails` (I'm still new).

**Alternative Solution:**
If the dynamic `root_path` isn't possible, then the alternative would be to go down the road of an `authenticated_root` and an `unauthenticated_root` as I have in the above `routes.rb`.

Comment: How are you setting calling these in your view?

Comment: After using @satoshy's solution, I am now just using `<%= link_to "Home", '/' %>` instead of `<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this `authenticated_root_path`